# Error when submitting transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have a little bit unusual problem. Following code works in online playground, but id doesn't work when i'm using generated API on rest server deployed locally. When trying to post transaction i get an error. 
cto file:

```
namespace org.dps.track

asset Item identified by itemId{
    o String itemId
    o String name
    o String idgId
    o String serialNumber
    o String comment
    --> BU owner
    --> Item [] items optional
}

participant BU identified by buId{
    o String buId
    o String name
    o String country
    o String city
}

participant Assembler extends BU{
}

participant Manufacturer extends BU{
}

transaction Trade{
    --> Item item
    --> BU newOwner
}

enum status{
  o IN_TRANSIT
  o DEPARTURED
  o DELIVERED
}
```

chaincode:

```
/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.dps.track.Trade } trade - the sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {

    const factory = getFactory();
    trade.item.owner = trade.newOwner;
    var list = [];
    if (trade.item.items && trade.item.items.length > 0) {
        trade.item.items.forEach((asset) => {
        list.push(asset);
        });
    }  


    const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.dps.track.Item');


    // persist the state of the current ITEM
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.item);

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {

         let res = await assetRegistry.get(list[i].getIdentifier());
         res.owner = factory.newRelationship('org.dps.track', 'Assembler', trade.newOwner.getIdentifier());
         // persist the state of the ITEM with new owner as a relationship
         await assetRegistry.update(res);
    }

}
```

When trying to post transaction via Rest API i get error:

```
{

  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.dps.track.Trade#e4764be8e037c7186774512860c0cde6d7eaed5c301ddf36c4c1ab560577861a",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.dps.track.Trade#e4764be8e037c7186774512860c0cde6d7eaed5c301ddf36c4c1ab560577861a\n    at HLFConnection.invokeChainCode (/home/bryczek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:1002:30)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

Has anyone an idea what is wrong? I would be really thankful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your model file, not the transaction code. You need `Assembler` not `BU` in the relationship field for `Item` and for `Trade`

1. Your asset should be:

```
    asset Item identified by itemId{
            o String itemId
            o String name
            o String idgId
            o String serialNumber
            o String comment
            --> Assembler owner
            --> Item [] items optional
        }
```

as `Assembler` is the resource class (not BU, which is an extended class - there is no registry for this).

2. Your transaction `Trade` should also reflect the same resource ie (not BU) :

```
     transaction Trade{
            --> Item item
            --> Assembler newOwner
        }
```

Other than that, it should work fine with your existing code (have tested it against a Fabric network, using the following example `Trade` transaction in my REST API, where previous owner was `Assembler#1` and it changes related `Items` from the `items` array for `Item` #1)

```
{
  "$class": "org.dps.track.Trade",
"item":"resource:org.dps.track.Item#1",
"newOwner":"resource:org.dps.track.Assembler#2"
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, I modified cto as below, but no APIs are generated. I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I modified model file and now whe n trying to generate rest API i only get System(General business network methods), no Item, BU and Trade API, why is this happening?

cto:

```
/**
 * New model file
 */

namespace org.dps.track


//asset section
asset Item identified by itemId{
    o String itemId
    o String name
    o String idgId
    o String serialNumber
    o String comment
    --> BU owner
    --> Item [] items optional

} 

//participant section
participant BU identified by buId{
    o String buId
    o String name
    o String country
    o String city
    o participantType type
}


//tranasaction section

transaction Trade{
    -->Item item
    -->BU newOwner
}

enum status {
    o IN_TRANSIT
    o DEPARTURED
    o DELIVERED
}

enum participantType{
    o Manufacturer
    o Assembler
}
```

cc:

```
/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.dps.track.Trade } trade - the sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {

    const factory = getFactory();
    trade.item.owner = trade.newOwner;
    var list = [];
    if (trade.item.items && trade.item.items.length > 0) {
        trade.item.items.forEach((asset) => {
        list.push(asset);
        });
    }  


    const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.dps.track.Item');


    // persist the state of the current ITEM
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.item);

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {

         let res = await assetRegistry.get(list[i].getIdentifier());
         res.owner = factory.newRelationship('org.dps.track', 'BU', trade.newOwner.getIdentifier());
         // persist the state of the ITEM with new owner as a relationship
         await assetRegistry.update(res);
    }

}
```

Comment: how did you do the upgrade of your business network? You would minimally need to follow Steps Three and Four in this doclink https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries   .... then ......once the BN is upgraded, per that process, you would stop any running REST server instance, and start it again eg. `composer-rest-server` and, once you provide the right answers,  it should discover the newly upgraded business network, and reveal your new Model